# Meaning of . and .. directories in linux

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

When display hidden file and directory in terminal using `ls -la` it show two directory i.e. `. and ..` and when list the content of dot(.) directory it contain all file and directories that is in it's parent directory,are it create clone of that file, if yes then there is duplicate files ?

And while running a script we have use that dot directory if we are in directory where it reside like 
`./script`

but not when we run it from another directory like

`/Document/myscript/script`

why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- The `.` is same as saying "current directory". So `./script` means execute `script` file in current directory.
- The `..` is same as saying "parent directory" (one directory up).

Also, if you are in `/` directory, there is no difference between:

```
/Document/myscript/script
```

and

```
./Document/myscript/script
```

So when you use the dot (`.` or `..`), the path you provide is **relative** to current\parent directory you are in.

If you use full path, then the path is **absolute** path to the file.

Comment: Would I be right in adding that the reason for executing `./script` rather than `script` is that it prevents execution of an identically named script somewhere in your PATH (important if you mistype the script name)?

Comment: Yes you are correct. `./script` will execute script in current directory, while just `script` will look in `PATH`. I don't think it will look in current directory if it is not in `PATH`.

Comment: The PATH on Unix system does not include the current directory (.) as  a security precaution.

Comment: what do dots in the middle of paths do? (such as `/Documents/./myscript`)

Comment: Single dots inside a path have no effect as they are referring to the **then** current directory. So `x/y/./z` is the same as `x/y/z`. Double dots go up one level so, assuming that both y1 and y2 are directories inside directory x, `x/y1/../y2/z` is the same as `x/y2/z`